# AngularJS to get Salesforce data using REST API

Tags: angular

Below is my angular code to get contact. It runs locally using nodejs.

```
    angular.module('demoApp')
.factory('contactService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getContactDetails: function(quoteId) {
            var soql = 'SELECT Name FROM Contact Limit 1;
            var url = 'http://cs18.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/query?q=' + encodeURIComponent(soql);
            var sessionId = '00D1100000BzLId!ASAAQPOKAZvD05Q1Jy71YcLdkK0Y_tGwK1bqTUcFfYLS8THKJ5DJtC2VXmrswtBWvjjp';
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({url:url,method:'GET',headers:{'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + sessionId}}).success(function(data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(err, status) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;        
        }
    };
});
```

But it gives me this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://cs18.salesforce.com/services/data/v30.0/query?q=SELECT%20Name%2C%20A…oposal__Proposal_Name__c%20FROM%20Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c%20Limit%201.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

How can I fix it? Any thoughts?

Comment: Check out [forcetk](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit).

Answer (score 2):

Add below config headers in your Angualar JS Factory and white-list your VF page instance url in [salesforce CORS](http://sarvatsfdc.com/2015/07/07/salesforce-cors-to-fix-the-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/):

Check it out the :
http://sarvatsfdc.com/2015/08/07/angularjs-highcharts-wijmotable/ ( Angular JS Controller line # 290  )

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
 var sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";

 $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
 delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["content-type"] = "application/json";
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "OAuth " + sessionId ;
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-User-Agent'] = "MyClient" ;
}]) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience angular works like charm with JavaScript tempting services ... You achieve the same results by writing simple apex methods and consuming the json on angular side.

Comment: I have not hosted this code on Salesforce. It runs locally. That is why it is giving me this problem. How can I get data from salesforce in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [JSforce](https://jsforce.github.io/); I've used it for accessing the Salesforce REST API from a MEAN app before and it's pretty well-documented. It's also [open-sourced on GitHub](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce) and actively maintained by the authors.

Answer (score 0):

try running your browser with security diabled i.e. click start->run and type:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

the error you're getting is to do with CORS (cross origin resource sharing)